# How to replace permalinks

Tags: permalinks, localhost

I have exported and imported my wordpress project into live server. Now the problem is I have permalink structures as "localhost" format.
When I click on any links in my website it redirects me to localhost. How can I change that?
my .htaccess file is given below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myproject/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: just a side note. Always use `Duplicator` WordPress plugin for moving WordPress websites. It is quite a peace of mind. http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have not properly updated the "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" at wp-admin -> Settings -> General, or [you have `define`d `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in `wp-config.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) and did not adjust the value when the site was moved.

I can't comment on whether the `.htaccess` file is correct, though I can say that it *would be* correct for certain sub-directory installs.

Comment: if my local is localhost and live sever is mysite.com/myproject, what shoul be the wp_siteurl and wp_home ?

Comment: They most likely should both be `http://mysite.com/myproject` on the live server.